# loading a single jpg file into openseadragon displays multiple tiles

Tags: openseadragon

Loading a <s>large</s> jpg file using type of 'image' as in examples
from
https://openseadragon.github.io/examples/tilesource-image/
is showing up with multiple duplicate tiles on the viewport.
a missing configuration setting?

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
OpenSeadragon({
  id:            "openseadragon",
  prefixUrl:     "data/",
  debugMode:true,
  tileSources:   {
     type: 'image',
     url:  '../data/gudmap/large.jpg'
  }
});
```

[image: original image duplicated into 4 tiles]

[new] after more trying, it is not when the jpg file is big but when the jpg file is actually small that it gets duplicate into multiple tiles.

Answer (score 0):

The image tile source loads the single image you give it and breaks it into multiple tiles to make drawing more efficient. I imagine that's what you're seeing.

Comment: it is actually duplicated instead of partials of the original image

Comment: Oh! Very strange! Can you file an issue at https://github.com/openseadragon/openseadragon/issues and include a repro (like a Codepen or something)? Also, it might be worth building the latest OSD from master to see if it's working there.

Comment: After pulling in the latest OSD master source, the duplication went away.  all is well.

Comment: Great to hear! We're getting close to making another release, so hopefully it'll get cleared up for everyone soon.